# How to export each part of a line of text file to its own file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have these output values of an Arduino Sensor saved to text file like this

```
9 P2.5=195.60 P10=211.00
10 P2.5=195.70 P10=211.10
11 P2.5=195.70 P10=211.10
2295 P2.5=201.20 P10=218.20
2300 P2.5=201.40 P10=218.40
...
...
```

And I want to extract each column to its own text file.

Expected Output: **3 text Files** Number.txt, P25.txt and P10.txt where

Number.txt contains

```
9
10 
11 
2295 
2300
```

P25.txt contains

```
195.60 
195.70 
195.70 
201.20 
201.40
```

and P10.txt contains

```
211.00
211.10
211.10
218.20
218.40
```

PS: the file has more than just 5 lines, so the code should be applied to every line.

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do:

```
$ grep -Po '^[0-9.]+' data.txt > Number.txt
$ grep -Po '(?<=P2\.5=)[0-9.]+' data.txt > P25.txt
$ grep -Po '(?<=P10=)[0-9.]+' data.txt > P10.txt
```

---

- `^`: Assert position at the start of the line.
- `[0-9.]+` Matches either a digit or a dot, between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.
- `(?<=)`: Positive lookbehind.
- `P2\.5=`: Matches `P2.5=`.
- `P10=`: Matches `P10=`.

---

- `-o`: Print only matching part.
- `-P`: Perl style regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`, which can open files itself rather than rely on standard output.

```
awk '{sub("P2.5=", "", $2);
      sub("P10=", "", $3);
      print $1 > "Number.txt";
      print $2 > "P25.txt";
      print $3 > "P10.txt"; }' data.txt
```

or

```
awk '{print $1 > "Number.txt";
      print substr($2, 6) > "P25.txt";
      print substr($3, 5) > "P10.txt"; }' data.txt
```